# How to convert Html5 bootstrap template to Vue app?

Tags: html, templates, vuejs2, vuex

I have a good HTML 5 template and I want to convert it to the Laravel + Vue app.
How should I do then?
Thanks

Comment: Either you  can add cdn url of vue or for complete application, you can go through https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/

Comment: Hi Devang
I just wanted to use the template as it is but just vue format.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. Have integrated Vue + Bootstrap.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    
    <div id="app" class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-info">{{ message }}</div>
    <p><input v-model="message" class="form-control"></p>
    </div>

    <script>
    myObject = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {message: 'Hello Vue.js!'}
    })
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```